# How do I get the Package, categories and items associated with a Virtual Guest OR Baremetal using Softlayer Rest API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to find a way to get a consolidated response, having the details of a VirtualGuest's / BareMetal's Package , Categories , Items in the VirtualGuest or BareMetal.

Please suggest a way to get a consolidated Rest API for it.

Answer (score 0):

The details of a VirtualGuest’s/BareMetal’s package, category and items can be retrieved using the next object mask:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$virtualGuestId/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[billingItem[item,category,children[item,category]]]
Method: GET

https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/$hardwareId/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[billingItem[item,category,children[item,category]]]
Method: GET
```

You can also replace previous object mask with this one which retrieves data in a way much more succinctly:

> objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,billingItem[id,item[id,description],category[name,id],children[id,item[id,description],category[name,id]]]]

Additional helpful links:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters